# Kendo grid does not update data with custom dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, dropdown

I'm trying to use a Kendo grid with inline editing but my data does not change on pressing update. Other columns have no problem, but the drop down data is not updated.

My model class is:

```
public class Validation
{
    public string ParentParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterTitle { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DataTypeList")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    
    [UIHint("EvetHyir")]
    public string Required { get; set; }
    public List<Validation> Value { get; set; }
}
```

My grid is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Validation>()
    .Name("keyJsonGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(model => model.ParentParameterName).Title("Ana parametre ünvanı");
        columns.Bound(model => model.ParameterTitle).Title("Parametre ünvanı");
        columns.Bound(model => model.ParameterName).Title("Parametre Adı");
        //columns.Bound(foo => foo.DataType).Title("TİP").EditorTemplateName("DataType").Sortable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DataType).Sortable(false).Width(180).EditorTemplateName("DataTypeList");
        
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("Düzenle"); command.Destroy().Text("Sil"); }).Width(250);
    })
    .Resizable(builder => builder.Columns(true))
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Yeni Ekle"))
    .Editable(editable => editable
        .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
        .ConfirmDelete("Silinmesine emin misiniz?")
        .DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Silinmesine emin misiniz?")
    )
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 })
    )
    .Sortable(x => x.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetJsonKeyList", "Key", new { KeyId = Model }))
        .PageSize(25)
    )
)
```

My dropdown is populated from an enum:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    // The name of the widget has to be the same as the name of the property.
    .Name("DataType")
    // The value of the drop-down is taken from the EmployeeID property.
    .DataValueField("Text")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .AutoBind(true)
    // The text of the items is taken from the EmployeeName property.
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
    // A list of all employees which is populated in the controller.
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["DataTypes"]) 
)
```

Dropdown data population code:

```
KeyJsonDTO.DataType x = KeyJsonDTO.DataType.Integer;
ViewData["DataTypes"] = EnumToSelectList(x.GetType());

static List<SelectListItem> EnumToSelectList(Type enumType)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(enumType)
        .Cast<int>()
        .Select(i => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = i.ToString(),
            Text = Enum.GetName(enumType, i),
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

When I press the "Edit" button, the dropdown does not show correct data, and when I press update data, it does not update.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are actually using the dropdown you created.  "DataType" is not the name of the field.  It is the name of the editor template you save in the file system.  You can use controls on page but as far as i know, only if it's a javascript grid.  You need to make an editor template in the appropriate folder and change the definition of the control to be an dropdownfor(m => m).  Then you don't have to name it.